# How to create a standalone RESTful Service in Java to consume JSON?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, soap

I am trying to create a standalone RESTful Service in Java without a Web Server.
This service will consume JSON that's sent part of the request from client applications.

I can create a SOAP web service using JAX-WS but I want to create REST service that will be run without a web server. Please suggest how can I create this? Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you mean an _embedded_ server, rather than _no_ server. You can't run a REST service without a server. [See here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-from-archetype) for easy startup (maven archetype) Jersey example using an embedded grizzly server.

Comment: Spring is your friend, here. Specifically, [Spring Data Rest](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to choose spring boot to create Restful web services where it does not depend on web server. We can create and build the rest service as service.